# Get data from a module that act as a Server

Tags: delphi, indy

We have a device that operate in TCP server mode. So I must **connect to it** to start send and receive.

I connected to it with IdTcpClient. But I don't know how to get it's data using IdTcpClient
(IdTcpClient does not have an OnExecute event).

I get it's port(port is dynamic) to send data(I have a firewll). But I can not listen on that with IdTCPServer and I get this error: "Can not bind socket. Address and port already are in use".

How can I get the incoming data(with IdTcpClient) and send command to it? Do I have a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have connected to the device, you can read from it, and write to it, whenever you need to.  If you do not want to hang your main UI thread, you should do your socket I/O in a worker thread.  That works very well with Indy's blocking I/O model.  You can use `TThread` for that, and override its `Execute()` method.  Or use Indy's `TIdThreadComponent` component.

Comment: How can I read? For example IdTCPServer has a OnExecute event and I can read data with AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn, but IdTCPClient does not have such thing(I don't find).

Comment: TIdTCPClient has an IOHandler property.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the manual for your "device" at first. And find out what actions your device is expecting from you to read data. 
You can't open the same port 2 times.

Comment: This is a TCP connection. I'd prefer reading RFC related topic.

Comment: Internet standard protocols are published in RFCs. Just because a device uses TCP does not guarantee that it uses a standard Internet protocol for its communications.